# C# LightInject - How to replace an instance in a contain with another

Tags: c#, light-inject

Suppose I have ClassA and ClassB inherit from IClass. Now I have a LightInject container and register an instance of ClassA as

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
Helpers.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IClass), classA, "Class");
```

Now I want to replace classA with classB as

```
ClassB classB = new ClassB();
Helpers.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IClass), classB, "Class");
```

so that when I try to get an instance in another class can get classB rather than classA

```
(IClass) Helpers.Container.TryGetInstance(typeof(IClass), "Class");
```

However, I always get classA when I try to get an instance. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

**Update:**

I have an IF statement to control which instance I want to register, such as

```
if (name == "classA")
{
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    Helpers.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IClass), classA, "Class");
}
else
{
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    Helpers.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IClass), classB, "Class");
}
```

In my code, the first round, the condition will be true. Therefore, I will register classA to the container. The second round, the condition will be false. As a result, I hope classB will be registered to the container. When I try to get the instance, I will get classA after the first round and then get classB in the second round. However, the current situation is that in both rounds, I get classA.

Comment: Did you comment out the `Helpers.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IClass), classA, "Class");` line?

Comment: `if (true)` will always go into the first branch. what is the condition?

Comment: This is just an example. It can be any condition, such as if (name == "classA")

Comment: Did you try to remove instance from LifeTimeManager immediatly (in your case it is **ContainerControlledLifetimeManager**)? Retrive a registration `var registration = container.Registrations.FirstOrDefault(reg => /*reg.RegisteredType == typeof(IClass) &&*/ reg.LifetimeManagerType == typeof(ContainerControlledLifetimeManager) && reg.Name == "Class");` and then `registration.LifeTimeManager.RemoveValue(); registration.LifeTimeManager.SetValue(classB)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of LightInject.

Might be because you are trying to register a service after it has been resolved. Hard to say without a complete example. Create an issue in the LightInject repo with a link to small repro and we will help you out